# How to make <select> tag width auto based on the option you selected in react?

Tags: reactjs, select

I want to make my select tag change its width dynamically depending on the selected option. I've already tried to set a fontSize of the select tag to 16px and calculate width using this formula (selectedCategorie.length * 16) but I get an extra space for some options.
Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/loukil98/pen/ZELjqBv?editors=0010

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Select = () => {
    const [selectedCategorie, setSelectedCategorie] = useState("sqddsq")

    return (
        <div>
            <select
                value={selectedCategorie}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setSelectedCategorie(e.target.value)
                }}
                style={{width: `${selectedCategorie.length * 16}px`, fontSize: "16px"}}>
                <option>Toutes nos categories</option>
                <option>sqddsq</option>
                <option>jhgjgjg</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Select;
```

Comment: here's a jQuery solution that could help, using a secondary select with visibility hidden that duplicates the value of the visible select, then use the computed width of the helper select: https://webdevpuneet.com/make-select-tag-width-equal-to-the-selected-option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is already a great library can do this for you: @tag0/use-text-width

(source: I found the article from here: https://morioh.com/p/a8a3609efb78)

You can simply use the library to get the text size, then set it to the style of the `select`

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gettextwidth-zi45u?file=/src/App.tsx:23-728

```
import { useTextWidth } from "@tag0/use-text-width";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedCategorie, setSelectedCategorie] = React.useState("sqddsq");

  const width = useTextWidth({ text: selectedCategorie, font: "16px Arial" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        value={selectedCategorie}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSelectedCategorie(e.target.value);
        }}
        style={{ width: width + 24, fontSize: "16px", fontFamily: "Arial" }}
      >
        <option>Toutes nos categories</option>
        <option>sqddsq</option>
        <option>jhgjgjg</option>
        <option>wxcwxc</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice: in `style={{ width: width + 24, fontSize: "16px", fontFamily: "Arial" }}`, the 24 is the width of the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I could imagine is to render a second invisible `select` and add only one `option` element to it with the current selected value (which is `selectedCategorie` in your case).
Then you can always set the visible select width to the width of the invisble select using a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver/disconnect) to detect size changes:

```
const Select = () => {
    const [selectWidth, setSelectWidth] = React.useState(undefined)
    const [selectedCategorie, setSelectedCategorie] = React.useState("sqddsq");
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const resize_ob = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => setSelectWidth(entry.contentRect.width));
        resize_ob.observe(document.querySelector("#width_tmp_select"));

        return () => resize_ob.disconnect();
    }, [])
  
    return (
        <div>
            <select
                value={selectedCategorie}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setSelectedCategorie(e.target.value)
                }}
                style={{ width: selectWidth, fontSize: "16px" }}>
                <option>Toutes nos categories</option>
                <option>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM</option>
                <option>sqddsq</option>
                <option>jhgjgjg</option>
                <option>wxcwxc</option>

            </select>
        
            <select id="width_tmp_select" style={{fontSize: "16px", visibility: "hidden"}}>
              <option>{selectedCategorie}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```